# UIScrollView continues swipe issue with paging enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, swipe, paging

Following method working fine to get current question index in my scroll view with paging enabled:

```
int currentQueIndex = 0;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
        CGFloat pageWidth = sender.frame.size.width;
        NSInteger offsetLooping = 1;
        int page = floor((sender.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + offsetLooping;

        currentQueIndex =  page % [allQuestions count];
        NSLog(@"Current Question Index :%d",currentQueIndex);
}
```

Swipe normally to see next question :-

**Current Question Index :1**

Again swipe normally to next question :-

**Current Question Index :2**

Now I continously swipe multiple times, say 3 times, I'm getting :-

**Current Question Index :5**

instead of

**Current Question Index :3**

**Current Question Index :4**

**Current Question Index :5**

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat scrollPosition = scrollView.frame.size.width/scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    int index = (int)round(scrollPosition);
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer Armands, but it is getting called multiple times and giving wrong index.